# Read lines as variable in parallel (Bash)

Tags: bash

I have this script currently and it works fine, however it would be great if it could run 4-5 of these lines in parallel as I have extra resources available.

How could this be accomplished? I have tried removing thee IFS=read warped around it to read it in externally, but that didnt work for me.

```
    while IFS= read -r line

    do
      echo "$line"

    var1=$line

#warped script location#

done < /home/somanyvarlines.txt
```

Comment: `xargs -P5 -d '\n' the_script < input.txt` or `parallel`

Comment: When the script works fine, you do not need parallel. When it doesn't perform, it is likely that you are calling different programs again-and-again-and-again in your loop. Perhaps show the part that doesn't perform, that can be fixed.

Comment: The command runs as shown, but its only using the initial line as the variable. Using parallel worked with the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you wanted :

```
n=5
while readarray -n $n -t five; test ${#five[@]} != 0; do
    printf "%s\n" "${five[@]}"
    # Do your stuff with array of 5 : "${five[@]}"
done < /home/somanyvarlines.txt
```

Comment: This almost worked, however it set ${five[@]} as the literal output for all of the references to the variable regardless if it was used directly or used like var=${five[@]}

Comment: You can reference `five` in different ways, like `${five[@]}`, `${five[*]}`, or ${five[0]}...Why you need to assign to another variable ?